# Flutter how to read the device capabilities?

Tags: flutter, casting, chromecast, google-cast, mdns

Flutter application, I am using ***Bonsoir 2.0.0*** to fetch the available devices. I use service type as **_googlecast._tcp**. I am able to detect devices but I would like to filter the devices based on device capabilities like video and audio, video only, audio only etc.

Is there any way to find the detected device capabilities which is similar to android cast library code as shown here [Android CastDevice capabilities](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/CastDevice#hasCapabilities(int%5B%5D)). This is not available in the Bonsoir package.

Following is the work already done.
I am able to see the service info of the device which is mentioned below. I see that, there is property called 'cd'. Is this something relared to capabilities. But I am not clear how to identify correctly.

Sample device info for audio only device is here:

```
{
   "service.name":"Google-Nest-Mini-f085fd9042490e01a04233c8bf333778",
   "service.type":"_googlecast._tcp",
   "service.port":8009,
   "service.attributes":{
      "bs":"FA8FCA78A8D0",
      "cd":"5810A9FF37B193370398E3678764CF83",
      "rs":"",
      "st":"0",
      "md":"Google Nest Mini",
      "fn":"Office speaker",
      "nf":"1",
      "ic":"/setup/icon.png",
      "id":"f085fd9042490e01a04233c8bf333778",
      "rm":"",
      "ca":"199172",
      "ve":"05"
   },
   "service.ip":"192.168.*.**"
}
```

Appriciates your valuable suggestions or clues.

Answer (score 1):

Device capabilities seems to be in 'ca' attribute.

Filter ca attribute with bit mask described in https://github.com/openedx/edx-app-ios/blob/master/Libraries/Cast/GoogleCast.framework/Headers/GCKDevice.h

For your sample device, you will see that lower byte is 00000100 enabling capability GCKDeviceCapabilityAudioOut (device with audio out capabilities.)

I tested my home devices and all apears to conform with lower byte of ca attribute, also speaker groups.